# Get dorodown list selected value which is filled in javascript on button click event on server side

Tags: asp.net, list, drop-down-menu

I am using ASP.Net 3.5. 
I have fiiled dropdown list in javascript using ajax service but unable to get its selected value in button click event on server side.

Comment: Post some code.  Specifically, the aspx/ascx that declares the DropDownList and anything in the codebehind that accesses/modifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an asp.net server control or a select list generated by javascript?  If it is a javascript generated HTML element, you will not be able to use the .NET syntax such as

```
Dim x as string = controlID.selectedValue
```

You would need to do this the "old fashioned" way

```
Dim x as string = Request.Form("controlID")
```

Edit:  When I say ASP.NET control, that would look like

`<asp:dropdownlist id="controlID" runat="Server">
       <asp:listItem text="Some Value" value="1" />
  </asp:dropdownlist>`

and the HTML generated control would be 
`<select id="controlID" name="controlID><option value=1>Some Value</option></select>`